# Is it possible to put a gridview in the listview's header?

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I need to put 6 items with similar layouts on the header of a listview and am weighing out the pros and cons of using a gridview or just putting redundant code in the xml. And when I have put the layout in the listview's header I would then instantiate the adapter and put data on the gridview. Is it possible? And is it a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

Can a `GridView` be used as a header of a `ListView` ?

Yes, it can be used.As the method for adding it is `addHeaderView(View v)`.
As evident from the function argument it takes any `View` object.So a gridView can work.

Is it a good design ?

Well, I have never tried it. But the header View is something that needs to be very short in terms of amount of information it displays.Having a `GridView` in that sense makes a `bad solution`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am going to wait for more opinions before deciding what to use :)

Comment: fair enough. But just a suggestion if you could actually update some images of what you would expect your final gui to look like. That would increase the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an simpler solution would be to use a table layout and include the specific .xml file so you don't have redundant code in your .xml

Example:

```
   <TableLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <TableRow>

         <include
            android:id="@+id/one"
            layout="@layout/some" />

         <include
            android:id="@+id/two"
            layout="@layout/some" />

         <include
            android:id="@+id/three"
            layout="@layout/some" />
      </TableRow>

      <TableRow>

         <include
            android:id="@+id/four"
            layout="@layout/some" />

         <include
            android:id="@+id/five"
            layout="@layout/some" />

         <include
            android:id="@+id/six"
            layout="@layout/some" />
      </TableRow>
   </TableLayout>
```

Still not pretty but i think it is better than using lists in lists (what should never be done. Like listviews in scrollviews :) )

Comment: Won't using a TableLayout + TableRows be the same as using multiple LinearLayouts in terms of overhead memory?

Comment: Yes i think LinearLayout would be enough in this situation

Answer (score 0):

Putting scroll container within another scroll container is `not a good design`. If you indeed want to put grid as header , you need to **`measure`** height of your gridview dynamically and then set height of it.

The answer given by @PaMaDo is good when you are having only 6 items , but may be in future you require more elements then it will be pain.

If you are creating it now ,May be trying `RecyclerView` with `gridlayoutmanager` help. But it would require some logic to implement spanCount as in [This](http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html).